# mouseenter/mouseleave ignoring covering element

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, mouseenter, mouseleave

It seems that the **mouseenter**/ **mouseleave** method is trigger not only when the mouse's coordinate enters the target's client rectangles, but also when another element uncover or cover the target. This is a problem because in my **mouseenter** callback, I want to display another element  E on top of the target. I also want E to disappear upon **mouseleave**. You can think of this as a overlapping tooltip.

However, when I move my mouse onto the target, **mouseenter** is fired and element E will cover it. This coverage futher triggers a **mouseleave** event, so E will disappear. This further triggers a **mouseenter** event so E will appear again..... Which is quite a headache.

So basically, I am wondering whether there is a version of **mouseenter**/ **mouseleave** that only care about whether the mouse enters or leaves the client rectangles of the target, regardless whether the target is covered or not.

update: @arunopjohny created a JS fiddle to illustrate this problem. See comments

Comment: You can place the overlapping element as a descendant of the target, so that the mouseenter/mouseleave events will not get trigered

Comment: The problem is that the target is inline whereas E is block level. Put E as descendant of the target will drive the browser crazy.. @ArunPJohny

Comment: whether http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9fNcY/1/ shows your problem

Comment: @ArunPJohny Exactly, thanks for creating that. As you can see, there is a short glitch as a sequence of (mouseenter, mouseleave, mouseenter) is fired, instead of a single mouseenter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found perfect solution in a relevant question: [Ignore mouse interaction on overlay image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657319/ignore-mouse-interaction-on-overlay-image)

The "pointer-events: none;" property will disable any mouse event of the element. More importantly, the event will instead "go through" to the element beneath it. Using this on the overlay element E in my question solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#target').hover(function () {
        var $target = $(this);
        clearTimeout($target.data('hoverTimer'));
        $('#e').show();
    }, function () {
        var $target = $(this);
        var timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $('#e').hide();
        }, 200);
        $target.data('hoverTimer', timer);
    });

    $('#e').hover(function () {
        clearTimeout($('#target').data('hoverTimer'));
    }, function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9fNcY/)

Comment: This solved the problem when target and E has exactly the same position and size. But if E is larger than target, then it won't disappear when you move the mouse out of just the target.

Comment: @user690421 can you help to recreate the problem in the fiddle

Comment: Yes. That illustrates the problem. But maybe it is the desired behavior on a second thought.

Comment: @user690421 what is the desired behavior?

Comment: Solution found, as mentioned in my own answer. Thank you for the nice discussion. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Up5jY/

Comment: The desired behavior is the E shall not interact with mouse event at all. It shall only show and hide and the mouse entering or leaving shall be solely dependent on target.