# Lags on onmousemove and div position

Tags: javascript, position, onmousemove

I'm trying to achieve a Glass Magnifier in JS.
But something wrong when I try to set the position of my glass regarding to the cursor position: if I try to set the glass position to the center of the cursor, lags happened and I can't figure out why.
I've tried to set a transform : translation (-50%, -50%) to my glass, but results are the same.

More than my glass position is far from the center of the cursor, less is bugged.

```js
let img = document.querySelector('.longboard');
let glass = document.querySelector('#zoom');
let displayCoor = document.querySelector('.coordonnees');
let a = glass.offsetWidth / 2;
let b = glass.offsetHeight / 2;


img.onmousemove = function(e) {zoomMovement(e)};


function mousemovement(e) {
    let x = e.pageX;
    let y = e.pageY;
    let coor = "Coordinates: (" + x + "," + y + ")";
    displayCoor.innerHTML = coor;
    return {x : x, y : y};
};

function zoomMovement (e){
    var pos = mousemovement(e);
    glass.style.top = (pos.y-b) +'px'; //<-- increase b to avoid the lag
    glass.style.left = (pos.x-a) +'px';//<-- increase a to avoid the lag
}

/*img.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
    document.getElementById('zoom').className = "visible";


});
img.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
    document.getElementById('zoom').className = "invisible";
});*/
```

```css
.visible{
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.invisible{
    display: none;
}
#zoom{
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url("https://scene7.zumiez.com/is/image/zumiez/Zoom_PDP/Santa-Cruz-Space-Wolf-40%26quot%3B-Drop-Down-Longboard-Complete-_288601-front-US.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Loupe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
     <img class="longboard" src="https://scene7.zumiez.com/is/image/zumiez/Zoom_PDP/Santa-Cruz-Space-Wolf-40%26quot%3B-Drop-Down-Longboard-Complete-_288601-front-US.jpg" style="position: relative; display: block;margin: 100px auto; width: 30%;"/>
    </div>
    <div class="coordonnees" style="display: block;margin: 30px auto"></div>
        <div id="zoom" class="visible"> </div>
    <script src="js/zoom3.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I will really appreciate if someone could explain me why.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "lag". But one issue I've found is that you're only listening to the mousemove event on your `img`. So, if you're moving your cursor inside your zoom, the glass manifier is not moving. This is because your `glass` has a higher `z-index` than your `img`. So, the mousemove event is not triggered as long as you don't move your cursor out of the `glass`.

To solve this, I only attached your event listener to the `glass` element and it seems smoother.

**EDIT** : I've found a much better solution using CSS `pointer-events:none` on your `glass` element.

Then, you can uncomment your eventListener that are showing and hiding your magnifier when your leave / enter the `img`

```js
let img = document.querySelector('.longboard');
let glass = document.querySelector('#zoom');
let displayCoor = document.querySelector('.coordonnees');
let a = glass.offsetWidth / 2;
let b = glass.offsetHeight / 2;


img.onmousemove = function(e) {zoomMovement(e)};
// previous solution : listening to mousemove on the magnifier : 
// glass.onmousemove = function(e) {zoomMovement(e)};

function mousemovement(e) {
    let x = e.pageX;
    let y = e.pageY;
    let coor = "Coordinates: (" + x + "," + y + ")";
    displayCoor.innerHTML = coor;
    return {x : x, y : y};
};

function zoomMovement (e){
    var pos = mousemovement(e);
    glass.style.top = (pos.y-b) +'px'; //<-- increase b to avoid the lag
    glass.style.left = (pos.x-a) +'px';//<-- increase a to avoid the lag
}

img.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
    document.getElementById('zoom').className = "visible";


});
img.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
    document.getElementById('zoom').className = "invisible";
});
```

```css
.visible{
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.invisible{
    display: none;
}
#zoom{
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url("https://scene7.zumiez.com/is/image/zumiez/Zoom_PDP/Santa-Cruz-Space-Wolf-40%26quot%3B-Drop-Down-Longboard-Complete-_288601-front-US.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    z-index: 2;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Loupe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
     <img class="longboard" src="https://scene7.zumiez.com/is/image/zumiez/Zoom_PDP/Santa-Cruz-Space-Wolf-40%26quot%3B-Drop-Down-Longboard-Complete-_288601-front-US.jpg" style="position: relative; display: block;margin: 100px auto; width: 30%;"/>
    </div>
    <div class="coordonnees" style="display: block;margin: 30px auto"></div>
        <div id="zoom" class="visible"> </div>
    <script src="js/zoom3.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi!
In fact, I am only listening to the mousemove event on my .img because the glass should appear only on the .img (exactly like this example: https://codepen.io/AGvin/pen/mqKsC but without any jquery)

But you get a point: every time the glass appear below my mouse, my mouse is not on my .img anymore, that's why it's seems to be "laggy"!

Comment: @Avaenity check my edit. I've found a much better solution using CSS. Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657319/ignore-mouse-interaction-on-overlay-image

Comment: WOAW! PERFECT! Know i understand where was my mistake and i got a solution! Just perfect! Thanks for all @RogerC!